# What is the better and optimal way to find the key (can be n-level nested ) is present in the mongoDB collection?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, nosql, aggregation

Let us take my document in collection looks like this bellow

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "MainId": 1111,
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Homes",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "CategoryID": 1,
                    "CategoryName": "Example"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MainId": 122,
            "firstName": "James",
            "lastName": "Watson",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "CategoryID": 2,
                    "CategoryName": "Example2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "messages": [], // blank json
    "success": true // boolean value
}
```

so i need to search  whether the key exists `CategoryID`   in the document or not , It is just an example my search key can be anything and can be nested to any level

what is an better and optimal way to find whether the key exists or not ?
`Note: each document structure might vary so need to find whether the key is present in the whole collection or not`

i can iterate through all the documents in the collection and recursively go as deep as inside to check the existing of the key but that is brute force solution how can i optimise it..?

What i need is:

- MongoDb aggregation query if exists
- OrElse any other way to do it in better and optimal way

Answer (score -1):

You can add `presentKeys` array field and be pushing to it all the keys you're setting in a document.

Here's how it can look like for your given example:

```
{
    "presentKeys": [
        "data",
        "data.MainId",
        "data.firstName",
        "data.lastName",
        "data.categories",
        "data.categories.CategoryID",
        "data.categories.CategoryName",
        "messages",
        "success",
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "MainId": 1111,
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Homes",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "CategoryID": 1,
                    "CategoryName": "Example"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MainId": 122,
            "firstName": "James",
            "lastName": "Watson",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "CategoryID": 2,
                    "CategoryName": "Example2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "messages": [], // blank json
    "success": true // boolean value
}
```

And then index that field to avoid full collection scan:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ presentKeys: 1 });
```

---

Now you can query documents that contain some key this way:

```
db.collection.find({ presentKeys: "data.categories.CategoryID" });
```

Comment: This didn't address OP's question as they excited the constraint: "_my search key can be anything and can be nested to any level_"

Comment: @user20042973 thanks, I've updated my answer, could you please have a look

Comment: @PavelBely thanks for your answer, but i need to do without altering the document,